# Google maps async load: It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-maps-api-3

This one just sents me troubleshooting for a bit, so I thought it may be worth a Q&A format.

Q: I'm trying to asynchronously load google maps via API (something similar to [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async))
But google maps loader complains

> Execute write on doc: It isn't possible to write into a document from
>   an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly
>   opened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A:
It's possible that your url string just has a typo.
Lets say you played with args and ended up with

url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp`?`callback=callback`

google maps won't recognize the callback option and fetch the sync `js` script that uses a call to document.write(), instead of loading the correct async version.
You can check for yourself, if after load you have a maps.googleapis.com script maps/api/js?v=3.. and it contains a `getScript`call containing `document.write()`, you've ended up in the wrong (sync) version..

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33358525/1487102)

Specify `&callback=someWindowFunction` in your api request and `document.write` won't get called