# Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document' error in loading angular google map

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

i am using angularjs in a web development project and using Angular Google Maps
api was recommended to me for adding google map to my project. 
it was very useful api but when i load it in my project using [this](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/use) quick start it crash some time and throw this exception to me:

> Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write
>   into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless
>   it is explicitly opened.

and some time it work nice. i searched in google and now i know this problem is because of loading google map after loading page. anyone can help me to find a solution to load map to partial html form after loading asynchronously?

Comment: Maybe you should try the documentation directly. [**doc**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API). And here's a similar problem: [**Link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354358/how-do-i-load-google-maps-external-javascript-after-page-loads). Hope this can be a reference to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify `&callback=someWindowFunction` in your api request and `document.write` won't get called

```
var _this = this;
window["googleMapsLoad"] = function () {
    _this.googleMapsLoaded = true;

    if (_this.initialized) {
        _this.reportReady();
        _this.createMap();
    }
}; 

this.initialize = function (reportReady) {
    this._super(false);

    if (this.googleMapsLoaded) {
        this.reportReady();
        this.createMap();
    }
};

var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=googleMapsLoad";

document.head.appendChild(script);
```