# Google MAP API Key in Angular App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, iis, mime-types

I have an angular app and trying to add a simple google map to a page. But I'm getting this:

```
> Google Maps API is required. Please register the following JavaScript
> library http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true. <div
> data-ui-view="" class="ng-scope">(anonymous function) @
> angular.js:11598$get @ angular.js:8548$ @ angular.js:8219v @
> angular.js:7726g @ angular.js:7075(anonymous function) @
> angular.js:6954k @ angular-ui-router.min.js:7k.compile @
> angular-ui-router.min.js:7$ @ angular.js:8217v @ angular.js:7726g @
> angular.js:7075g @ angular.js:7078(anonymous function) @
> angular.js:6954compile @ angular-ui-router.min.js:7$ @
> angular.js:8217v @ angular.js:7726g @ angular.js:7075(anonymous
> function) @ angular.js:6954k @ angular-ui-router.min.js:7k.compile @
> angular-ui-router.min.js:7$ @ angular.js:8217v @ angular.js:7726g @
> angular.js:7075(anonymous function) @ angular.js:6954compile @
> angular-ui-router.min.js:7$ @ angular.js:8217v @ angular.js:7726g @
> angular.js:7075(anonymous function) @ angular.js:6954k @
> angular-ui-router.min.js:7(anonymous function) @
> angular-ui-router.min.js:7$get.l.$broadcast @
> angular.js:14707x.transitionTo.x.transition.I.then.x.transition.x.transition
> @ angular-ui-router.min.js:7(anonymous function) @
> angular.js:13175$get.l.$eval @ angular.js:14388$get.l.$digest @
> angular.js:14204(anonymous function) @ angular.js:14427e @
> angular.js:4902(anonymous function) @ angular.js:5282
> js?sensor=true&_=1435321003344:8 Failed to execute 'write' on
> 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an
> asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.
```

The page below is a sample I downloaded from https://codeload.github.com/hpneo/gmaps/
 and the weird thing is that it works OK if I browse it over **http://myapp/directroy/map.html** but it's giving me the error above if I want to reach there over http://myapp/ng-route-to-map-page

I tried to register the javascript sdk over code.google.com and include the library into the page as

Am I doing this wrong? I put the API Key to there

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?&key=APIKEY"></script>
```

But still getting the same error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>GMaps.js &mdash; Geometry overlays</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="../gmaps.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.3.0/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="examples.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var map, rectangle, polygon, circle;
    $(document).ready(function(){
      map = new GMaps({
        el: '#map',
        lat: -12.043333,
        lng: -77.028333
      });
      var bounds = [[-12.030397656836609,-77.02373871559225],[-12.034804866577001,-77.01154422636042]];
      rectangle = map.drawRectangle({
        bounds: bounds,
        strokeColor: '#BBD8E9',
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: 3,
        fillColor: '#BBD8E9',
        fillOpacity: 0.6
      });

      var paths = [[-12.040397656836609,-77.03373871559225],[-12.040248585302038,-77.03993927003302],[-12.050047116528843,-77.02448169303511],[-12.044804866577001,-77.02154422636042]];
      polygon = map.drawPolygon({
        paths: paths,
        strokeColor: '#25D359',
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: 3,
        fillColor: '#25D359',
        fillOpacity: 0.6
      });
      var lat = -12.040504866577001;
      var lng = -77.02024422636042;
      circle = map.drawCircle({
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng,
        radius: 350,
        strokeColor: '#432070',
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: 3,
        fillColor: '#432070',
        fillOpacity: 0.6
      });
      for(var i in paths){
        bounds.push(paths[i]);
      }
      var b = [];
      for(var i in bounds){
        latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(bounds[i][0], bounds[i][1]);
        b.push(latlng);
      }
      for(var i in paths){
        latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(paths[i][0], paths[i][1]);
        b.push(latlng);
      }
      map.fitLatLngBounds(b);
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>GMaps.js &mdash; Geometry overlays</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span11">
      <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
      <p>You can draw geometry overlays (which can be a polygon or a rectangle or a circle):</p>
      <pre>polygon = map.drawRectangle({
  bounds: bounds,
  strokeColor: '#BBD8E9',
  strokeOpacity: 1,
  strokeWeight: 3,
  fillColor: '#BBD8E9',
  fillOpacity: 0.6
});
polygon = map.drawPolygon({
  paths: paths,
  strokeColor: '#25D359',
  strokeOpacity: 1,
  strokeWeight: 3,
  fillColor: '#25D359',
  fillOpacity: 0.6
});
circle = map.drawCircle({
  lat: lat,
  lng: lng,
  radius: 350,  //350 meters
  strokeColor: '#432070',
  strokeOpacity: 1,
  strokeWeight: 3,
  fillColor: '#432070',
  fillOpacity: 0.6
});</pre>
      <p>Be careful with the settings as they are not the same for each overlay.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a Google map inside an Angular application you should use the [Angular google maps directive](https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/).

Simply install using bower

```
bower install angular-google-maps
```

Load scripts in your HTML page

*Note that the API key provided by Google can be specified at the tail end of the maps.googleapis script reference.*

```
<script src='/path/to/lodash[.min].js'></script>
<script src='/path/to/angular-google-maps[.min].js?key=123...'></script>
<script src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'></script>
```

Inject dependency in your app

```
angular.module('myApplicationModule', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps']);
```

Add a map to your scope

```
$scope.map = { center: { latitude: 45, longitude: -73 }, zoom: 8 };
```

And add a map to your template, done!

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'></ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Don't forget to specify height in your CSS

```
.angular-google-map-container { height: 400px; }
```

You don't have to specify API key but if you don't, expect to see:

> NoApiKeys developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/…

Comment: I need to use GMaps Library

Comment: and these first lines if (!(typeof window.google === 'object' && window.google.maps)) {
  throw 'Google Maps API is required. Please register the following JavaScript library http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true.'
}
 are causing it. I think some kind of async loading needed but couldnt figure it

Answer (score 0):

OK. My problem here was I was referencing the maps api twice. Once in my parent page and also in the map page -child- I included it in resolve.

Once I removed the one in the parent page, my problem resolved. Maybe, it helps others having the same issue. Just check the references. On the other hand, I don't find it proper to give an error such as `Google Maps API is required. Please register the following JavaScript` in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33358525/1487102)

Specify `&callback=yourCallback` in the api request and `document.write` won't get called, where

`window["yourCallback"] = function () {}; // compiler minified dot notation for me`

Either that, or have the `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js` script tag inside of your HTML as it's getting parsed the first time, like in a newly constructed iframe or server response as a string.

I believe it's the network request "referrer" which is checked against your `&client=yourClientID` and `&signature=yourHMACSHA1EncodedSignature`, so make sure your `window.location.href` matches the request header if you're going to sign it. `document.referrer` in an iframe will show the parent frame's url unless they block it (security concern for some sites)

`document.write` would clear your document if it happened at a later time, so it's prevented